# Extract the version from the string using python?

Tags: python, regex

Extract the version number from the below-given string:

```
String 1: ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.2(50r)SYS3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Output: 12.2
Desired Output: 12.2(50r)SYS3

String 2: ROM: IOS-XE ROMMON
Output : 
Desired Output: IOS-XE ROMMON

String 3: ROM: 15.1(1r)SG18
Output: 15.1
Desired Output: 15.1(1r)SG18
```

Using the code below I got above output:

```
def version_parser(v):
    versionPattern = r'\d+(=?\.(\d+(=?\.(\d+)*)*)*)*'
    regexMatcher = re.compile(versionPattern)
    return regexMatcher.search(v).group(0)
```

I want a single simplified code that I can apply in all three cases.

Comment: Some crude pattern could be `^ROM:\s*(?:.*Version\s*)?(.*?(?=,|$))`

Comment: Can you define what technically constitutes a version number? Defining that can help you/us to write a regex pattern.

Comment: What are you trying to match with `=?`? It means 0 or 1 occurrence of `=`

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
^ROM:.+?(\b[A-Z- ]{2,}$|\d[\w.()]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Ygi0s1/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific method, and is heavily dependenant on the formatting of the strings. Also it could definitely be simplified, but it's just a very rough example:

Code

```
strings = ["ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.2(50r)SYS3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)",
           "ROM: IOS-XE ROMMON",
           "ROM: 15.1(1r)SG18"]

#For each varient of string
for item in strings:
    #Split into "sections" of info
    sections = item.split(", ")
    found = False
    #Find occurrence of version tag
    #For each data point in info
    for data in sections:
        #If version number specified
        if (data[:7].lower() == "version"):
            print(data[8:])
            found = True
            break
            
    #Find occurrence of rom tag
    for data in sections:
        if (not found):
            if (data[:4].lower() == "rom:"):
                print(data[5:])
                break
```

Output

```
12.2(50r)SYS3
IOS-XE ROMMON
15.1(1r)SG18
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern I would use is `(\d+\\.\d*\(*\w*\)*\w*|\w+-\w+ \w+)`:

```
pattern = r'(\d+\.\d*\(*\w*\)*\w*|\w+-\w+ \w+)'
string1 = '''ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.2(50r)SYS3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
ROM: IOS-XE ROMMON
ROM: 15.1(1r)SG18
15.1(r)SG18
'''
print(re.findall(pattern, string1, flags=0))
```

This could be optimized if I knew more about the possible formats for the version.

```
OUTPUT: ['12.2(50r)SYS3', 'IOS-XE ROMMON', '15.1(1r)SG18', '15.1(r)SG18']
```

Comment: `\d*\w` is non-sense, `\d`  is included in `\w`. And, you have to escaped the dot.

Comment: you are right! I have updated as per your recommendation. Thank you!